# Abstract Algebra proof for quadratic extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $n$ be a square free integer and alpha belong to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$. If $N(\alpha)$ is a prime integer, then $\alpha$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$.

Here $N(\alpha)$ denotes the norm of $\alpha$.

How can I show this? I'll get back in the morning because it's super late right now!

Comment: Actually, $\alpha$ is prime, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074491).

Answer (score 5):

The key idea is that multiplicative maps preserve multiplicative properties (a fact which is brought to the fore in *divisor theory*). Here we wish to pullback the property of being an atom (irreducible) along the multiplicative norm map $\rm\:N\:$ (recall that prime $\iff$ atom in a UFD, here $\rm\:Na\in \mathbb Z\:$).

Recall, by [definiton](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/alternate-definition-of-prime-number/4399#4399), an atom (irreducible) is a nonunit which can't be split into nontrivial factors, i.e. $\rm\ x = y\ z\ \Rightarrow\ y|1\:\ or\:\ z|1\:,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:y\:$ or $\rm\:z\:$ is a unit (or, [equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/alternate-definition-of-prime-number/4399#4399), $\rm\:x\:|\:y\:\ or\:\ x\:|\:z).$ Now consider

**HINT** $\ $ atom $\rm Na,\:\ a = bc\ \Rightarrow\ Na = Nb\ Nc\ \Rightarrow Nb|1\ or\ Nc|1\ \Rightarrow\ b|1\ or\ c|1\ \Rightarrow\:$ atom $\rm\:a$

In fact much of the multiplicative structure of a number ring is reflected in its monoid of norms. For example, in many favorable contexts (e.g. Galois) a number ring enjoys unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does. For references (Bumby and Dade, Lettl, Coykendall) see my [sci.math post on 19 Dec 2007.](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/e2d24bd27e600942)

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that your answer is probably over the OP's head...but I liked it very much and was thinking along similar lines. +1. :)

Comment: @Pete Ha, [tables turned, touche!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/show-that-langle-2-x-rangle-is-not-a-principal-ideal-in-mathbb-z-x/38866#38866) Here I think that the hint is probably not over the OPs head - only the cultural background remarks - which can be ignored (but which may plant intuitive germs of more conceptual ideas that will later come to the fore).

Answer (score 2):

The norm is multiplicative. So, if $\alpha=\beta\gamma$ then $N(\alpha)=N(\beta) N(\gamma)$. If $N(\alpha)$ is prime, then one of $N(\beta)$ or $N(\gamma)$ is $\pm 1$. You now need that $N(\beta)=\pm 1$ iff $\beta$ is a unit, which comes directly from $N(\beta)=\beta\bar{\beta}$.