# General method for solving $ax\equiv b\pmod {n}$ without using extended Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the linear congruence equation $$ax\equiv b\pmod { n}.$$ One way to solve it is solving a linear Diophantine equation 
$$
ax+ny=b.
$$

I saw somebody solved it by another method somewhere I don't remember:

> Solve $144x\equiv 22\pmod { 71}$.
>   $$\begin{align}
> 144x\equiv 93 &\pmod { 71}\\
> 48x\equiv 31&\pmod { 71}\\
> 48x\equiv -40&\pmod { 71}\\
> 6x\equiv   -5&\pmod { 71}\\
> 6x\equiv   66&\pmod { 71}\\
> x\equiv    11&\pmod { 71}
> \end{align}
> $$

Instead of solving a Diophantine equation using extended Euclidean algorithm, he uses the rules of congruence such as

> If $a_1\equiv b_1\pmod {n}$ and $a_2\equiv b_2\pmod {n}$, then $a_1\pm a_2\equiv b_1\pm b_2\pmod {n}$.

Here are my **questions**:

- Does the second method always work?
- What's the general *algorithm* for solving $ax\equiv b\pmod {n}$ in this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this example it is simpler to note that

$$\rm mod\ 71\!:\ \ \frac{22}{144}\: \equiv\: \frac{11}{72}\:\equiv\: \frac{11} 1 $$

When the modulus is prime one can employ [Gauss's algorithm,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/not-understanding-simple-modulus-congruency/3230#3230) for example

$$\rm mod\ 29\!:\ \ \frac{1}8\: \equiv \frac{4}{32}\: \equiv\: \frac{4}{3}\:\equiv\: \frac{40}{30}\: \equiv\: \frac{11}{1}$$

I.e. scale $\rm A/B\ \to AN/BN\ $ by the least $\rm\:N\:$ so that $\rm\ BN > 29\:.\ $ Then reduce the numerator and denominator $\rm\ mod\ 29,\:$ and iterate. You will eventually obtain a denominator of $1$ since each step reduces the denominator. Isn't that sweet? That's they key idea that led Gauss to the first proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. unique factorization of integers.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367841/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-modular-arithmetic-equations-such-as-9x-equiv-33/2368266#2368266) for many methods to compute modular inverses and fractions.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a reference for the Gauss's algorithm you mentioned? I'm also curious about what if the modulus is not prime.

Comment: @Jack Follow the link (and its links) for a precise reference: Gauss: Disq. Arith. Art. 5, 1801. Note that the method may fail if the modulus is not prime.

Comment: **Note** $\ $ The correct reference is Gauss, *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, Art. 13 (p. 5 of English translation).

Comment: (+1) for mentioning Gauss. Well, I'm only centuries late to his party. From what you are writing it appears that my proof of [Euclid's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3559106/432081) is the same argument Gauss used in  his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*.