# Modular Inverses Discrete Math

Tags: logic

I have to find the modular inverse of a sequence of numbers. 
When I do the inverse of $5\pmod {37}$, I get $-7$.
$$37 = 7(5)+2$$
$$5 = 2(2)+1\text{, then}$$
$$2 = 1(37)-7(5).$$

so the inverse is $-7.$

But $-7\times 5 \pmod{37}$ is $2$. Shouldn't it be $1$?

I need to use this value for two later problems so it's messing it all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $5$ is coprime to $37,$ we know by [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) that  $5$ is invertible mod $37$. To compute the inverse one could employ the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (which can be implemented very conveniently by hand, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)). But that algorithm is a bit overkill for such small numbers. Instead, it's simpler to employ [Gauss's Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130934/242) and some twiddling as follows

$$\rm mod\ 37\!:\,\ \frac{1}5 \equiv \frac{7}{35}\equiv \frac{-30}{-2}\equiv 15$$

Comment: I tried using the equations below (which should be the extended euclidean algorithm), but it doesn't seem to be working 

$$37=7(5)+2$$
$$5=2(2)+1$$
$$2=1(1)+1$$
then
$$1=5−2(2)$$
$$1=5−2(37−7(5))$$
$$1=12(5)−2(37))$$

Comment: Please try the [convenient version of EEA](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) that I linked to. It is generally easier to apply and almost always *much* less prone to errors. The correct back-substitution above  is $$\rm 1 = 5 - 2(\color{#C00}2) = 5 - 2(\color{#C00}{37-7(5)}) = 5-2(-7)5 - 2\cdot 37 = (1\!+2\cdot 7)\cdot 5-2\cdot 37$$ Therefore $\rm\: 1 = 15\cdot 5 - 2\cdot 37\: \Rightarrow\ 1\equiv 15\cdot 5\ \, (mod\ 37)\ \ $