# Solve $91x\equiv 84\pmod{147}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

So, I posted a similar question to this, and I know that the equation is solvable because $\gcd(91,147) = 7$ and $7 \mid 84$.

Plugging into Wolfram Alpha, I found that the solution is a line $21n + 9$. I can't figure out a means of getting this answer, though.

I tried the following: $91x= 147m + 84 = 7(21m+12)$, but this differs from the WA solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Neurax

Comment: The way you formatted $7 | 84$ looks as if you may have been attempting to put some space between the vertical line and the numbers before and after it.  Standard usage is 7\mid 24.  I changed it.

Answer (score 4):

$91x= 147m + 84 = 7(21m+12) \iff 13x = 21m + 12\tag{division by $7$}$

i.e. Solve $\;13x \equiv 12 \pmod{21} \implies $

- solve $\;x = 12\cdot 13^{-1} \pmod{21}$

and you'll get $x\equiv 9\pmod{21}$.

Now, find all solutions, modulo 147: all integers $x = 9 + 21k \lt 147$

Comment: Nice Amy. I hope you come very soon.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, you just need to divide both sides by seven:

$13x = 12 + 21m \implies 13x \equiv 12 \pmod{21}$

Now find the inverse of 13 mod 21, by whatever means you like. The extended Euclidean algorithm works here, but it's small enough you can do it by hand: 13.

Multiply both sides by 13:
$$13x \equiv 12 \pmod{21}$$
$$169x \equiv 156 \pmod{21}$$
$$x \equiv 9 \pmod{21}$$

Comment: But you appear to have used magic, pulling the inverse of $13$ out of a hat. See my answer for one way to use math vs. magic, viz. $\rm\: 13 \equiv (1,-1)\ mod\ (3,7)\:$ so $\rm\:13^2\equiv (1,-1)^2 \equiv (1,1),\:$ i.e. it atisfies $\rm\:x^2\equiv 1\:$ mod $3$ and $7$ so also mod $21$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Below are a few solutions, by Gaussian inversion, idempotents, and CRT.

$\rm\displaystyle\:91x = 84\!+\!147n\iff 13x = 12\!+\!21n\iff mod\ 21\!:\ x \equiv \frac{12}{13} \equiv\frac{24}{26} \equiv \frac{3}5 \equiv \frac{12}{20} \equiv \frac{12}{-1} \equiv 9$

**OR** $ $ note $\rm\ 3\cdot 7\mid 12\cdot 14 = 13^2\!-\!1,\:$ so $\rm\:mod\ 21\!:\ 13^2\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\:x \equiv 13(13x)\equiv 13(12)\equiv 9$

**OR** $ $ by  CRT, $\rm\ mod\ \color{#C00}7\!:\ x = 12/13\equiv -2/-1\equiv \color{#C00}{2},\:$ so $\rm\:mod\ 21\!:\ x \equiv \color{#C00}{2\!+\!7n} \equiv 2,\color{#0A0}9,16.\:$ But $\rm\:mod\ 3\!:\ x\equiv 12/13\equiv \color{#0A0}0,\:$ so the solution must be $\rm\:x \equiv \color{#0A0}9\ \ (mod\ 21),\:$ since $\rm\:3\nmid 2,16.$

**Beware** $\ $ One can employ fractions $\rm\ x\equiv b/a\ $ in modular arithmetic (as above) only when the fractions have denominator $ $ *coprime* $ $ to the modulus $ $ (else the fraction may not (*uniquely) exist,* $ $  i.e. the equation $\rm\: ax\equiv b\,\ (mod\ m)\:$ might have no solutions, or more than one solution). The reason why such fraction arithmetic works here (and in analogous contexts) will become clearer when one learns about the *universal* properties of fraction rings (*localizations*).

The first method is a special case of [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130934/23500) for computing inverses. This always works for prime moduli, but may fail for composite moduli (in which case one may employ the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/318462/23500) to compute inverses).

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve the congruence 
$$(7\cdot 13)x\equiv 7\cdot 12\pmod{7\cdot 21}.$$
This is equivalent to 
$$13x\equiv 12\pmod{21}.$$
We can solve the congruence by multiplying through by the inverse of $13$ modulo $21$. It is however easier to replace $13$ by $-8$. So our congruence is equivalent to $-8x\equiv 12\pmod{21}$, which is equivalent to $-2\equiv 3\pmod{1}$. But we can replace $3$ by $-18$, and reach $x\equiv 9\pmod{21}$.

Modulo the original modulus $147$, that gives the solutions $x\equiv 9\pmod{147}$, $x\equiv 30\pmod{147}$, and so on, a total of $7$ solutions modulo $147$.

**Remark:** I would not worry about Alpha. Though it gets the right answer quite often, it doesn't *know* what it is doing.

Comment: ie. $\rm\displaystyle\ mod\ 21\!:\  \frac{12}{13}\equiv \frac{12}{-8}\equiv \frac{3}{-2}\equiv\frac {-18}{-2}\equiv 9.\:$ See my answer for remarks on the fractional viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;91x=84\pmod{147}\iff 91x=84+147k\iff13x=12+21k\ldots$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;13^{-1}=?\pmod{21}...$$

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the numerous other answers:

Apply the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021/13854)
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&1&1&1&1&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&2&-3&5&-13\\
0&1&-1&2&-3&5&-8&21\\
147&91&56&35&21&14&7&0
\end{array}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
5\cdot147-8\cdot91&=7\\
-13\cdot147+21\cdot91&=0
\end{align}
$$
$12$ times the top plus $k$ times the bottom
$$
(60-13k)\cdot147+\color{#C00000}{(-96+21k)}\cdot91=84
$$
Therefore,
$$
x\equiv-96\equiv9\pmod{21}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve

$\tag C 91x\equiv 84\pmod{147}$

We begin by writing down two equations,

$\tag {A0} 91 \times 1 = 84 + \color{red}{(}7\color{red}{)}$

$\tag Z 91 \times 2 = 147 + \color{red}{(}35\color{red}{)}$

Observe that if we multiply $\text{(Z)}$ by $a$ and subtract it from $\text{(A0)}$ we can write

$\tag 1 \text{A1 = A0} + a \times \text{Z} : \quad 91 \times (1 +2a) = 84 + 147 a + \color{red}{(}7 + 35a\color{red}{)}$

For a solution to exist there must be a minimum positive integer $a$ such that

$\tag 2 7 + 35a = 91q \quad \text{ for some positive integer } q$

Dividing out the factor of $7$ from both sides of $\text{(2)}$ we see that $a$ = $5$ and $q=2$ (use $\text{modulo-}13$ calculations).

Substituting back into $\text{(1)}$,

$\tag 3  91 \times (1 +10) = 84 + 147 \times 5 + \color{red}{(}91 \times 2\color{red}{)}$

or

$\tag 4  91 \times 9 = 819$

So we have a particular solution, $9 \pmod {147}$.

Solving the homogeneous equation $91z\equiv 0\pmod{147}$ is easy - factor out $7$ and recall that $13 \times 13 \equiv 1 \pmod{21}$ - to conclude that $z \equiv 0 \pmod{21}$.

So the general solution to the congruence equation $\text{(C)}$ is

$\tag{ANS} x = 9 + z \quad \text{ where } z \equiv 0 \pmod{21}$