# Linear Diophantine Equations: Integer Solutions $x,y$ exist for $ax+by=c$, but how do I find them by hand?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to find which of $133x+203y=38$, $133x+203y=40$, $133x+203y=42$, and $133x+203y=44$ have integer solutions. I know that only the third equation suffices for these conditions because $gcd(133,203)=7$ which only divides $42$, but how do I find the solution with smallest possible $x\geq 0$ for $133x+203y=42$?

How do I find solutions $a,b$ to the equation $19a+29b=1$ by hand?

Comment: Since $\gcd(19,29) = 1$, you can use Euclid's algorithm to find $a$ and $b$ such that $19a + 29b = 1$. Then multiply solutions by $6$ to get $x$ and $y$ such that $19x + 29y = 6$ or $133x + 203y = 42$.

Comment: Do you know Euclidean alogorithm?

Comment: @TMM Why $6$ Mr./Ms. TMM?

Comment: @Trancot: If $19a + 29b = 1$ then $19(6a) + 29(6b) = 6(19a + 29b) = 6$ so then $x = 6a$ and $y = 6b$ leads to a solution to $19x + 29y = 6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Note $\rm\ 19x\!+\!29y=6\, \Rightarrow\, mod\ 19\!:\ y \equiv \dfrac{6}{29}\equiv \dfrac{6}{10}\equiv \dfrac{12}{20}\equiv \dfrac{12}{1}\equiv -7\,\ $ so $\rm\,\ \color{#c00}{y = -7\!+\!19n},\:$ therefore $\rm\ x\, =\, \dfrac{6\!-\!29\,\color{#c00}y}{19} = \dfrac{6\!-\!29(\color{#c00}{-7+19n}))}{19}\, =\, 11\!-\!29n.$

**Beware** $\ $ One can employ fractions $\rm\ x\equiv b/a\ $ in modular arithmetic (as above) only when the fractions have denominator $ $ *coprime* $ $ to the modulus $ $ (else the fraction may not (*uniquely) exist,* $ $  i.e. the equation $\rm\: ax\equiv b\,\ (mod\ m)\:$ might have no solutions, or more than one solution). The reason why such fraction arithmetic works here (and in analogous contexts) will become clearer when one learns about the *universal* properties of fraction rings (*localizations*).

The above method is a special case of [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130934/23500) for computing inverses. This always works for prime moduli, but may fail for composite moduli (in which case one may employ the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/318462/23500) to compute inverses). Gauss's algorithm is often more efficient for manual calculations with small numbers.