# How to divide a number from both sides of from congruence equation from $79^{80}\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$ to $79^{79}\equiv x \pmod{100}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This problem is to solve $79^{79} \equiv x \pmod{100}$. I'm aware this may be solved by binomial expansion or other methods. But when we apply Euler's theorem we obtain $79^{80} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, which seems to be very close to our goal. I just need to divide 79 from both sides.

Now I can do this using a stupid method: by subtracting 100 from LHS to obtain -99, -199, -299,... until "X99" is divisible by 79. I then find that $79 \times(-81)=-6399$. So we obtain $79^{80} \equiv -6399 \pmod{100}$ and divides 79 on both sides as 79 is coprime of 100. This gives me $79^{79}\equiv-81\equiv19 \pmod{100}$.

My question is if there is a more systematic/standard way of carrying out a division on both sides, perhaps something related to "inverse" etc. A group theory/ring theory approach is welcome as well.

Comment: See my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407478/solving-a-linear-congruence/407482#407482 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318423/how-to-solve-13x-equiv-1-textmod-17

Comment: You can't use Fermat's Little Theorem here (unless you do it twice and combine it with the Chinese Remainder Theorem). You can use Euler's Theorem, though... As to finding multiplicative inverses modulo $N$, you can use the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I used Euler's theorem. Sometimes, people just call this theorem Fermat' little theorem since it is just a generalization.

Comment: In my experience... that just doesn't happen. I would strongly discourage you from calling the generalization "Fermat's Little Theorem", which is *very specifically* about prime moduli **only**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you Arturo. I'm curious how you derived $79^{80} \equiv 1 (\mod 100)$ with Fermat's little theorem: "unless you do it twice and combine it with the Chinese Remainder Theorem". As far as I can see, the Fermat's little theorem does not apply for $(\mod 2^2)$ and $(\mod 5^2)$ either.

Comment: @DanielLi: Fair point, I was hasty there. P.S. Use `\pmod{2}`, not `(\mod 2)`.

Comment: @DanielLi I expanded my answer to show how the geometric series is used to compute such inverses, and I added a final method using inverse reciprocity.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you very much, Bill. That's an amazing observation. I have seen this idea used everywhere unexpectedly, often related to inverse and invertibility. For example, just recently I saw a proof of existence of square root of an invertible operator $T$ using similar idea, by first breaking down $T$ to sum of nilpotent operator and identity. That's truly amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) form of the extended Euclidean algorithm is easiest, but here below is quicker.

$\!\bmod 100\!:\ (\color{#c00}{80\!-\!1})(80\!+\!1)\equiv -1,\ $ because $\  \color{#0a0}{80^2\equiv 0}$

therefore: $\ \ \  \color{#c00}{79}^{-1}\equiv -81\equiv \bbox[4px,border:1px solid #c00]{19}\ $ Generally if $\,\color{#0a0}{a^n\!\equiv 0}\,$ [this  iinverts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242) $1\!-\!a\,$ [unit + nilptotent] by using a terminating geometric series:  $\ \dfrac{1}{1\!-\!a} \equiv \dfrac{1-\color{#0a0}{a^n}^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\!\!}{1-a}\equiv 1\!+\!a\!+\cdots + a^{n-1}$

---

**Or** using  [a fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, and $\,79\equiv \color{#90f}{-21}\!:$

${\rm mod}\ 100\!:\,\ \dfrac{0}{100} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{1}{\color{#90f}{-21}} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}5}{\color{#0a0}{-5}} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{19}1\,$ or, $ $ in equational form

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \begin{array}{rrl} 
[\![1]\!]\!:\!\!\!& 100\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \ 0\\
[\![2]\!]\!:\!\!\!& \color{#90f}{-21}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \ 1\\
[\![1]\!]+5[\![2]\!]=:[\![3]\!]\!:\!\!\!& \color{#0a0}{{-}5}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \  \color{#c00}5\\
-[\![2]\!]+4[\![3]\!]=:[\![4]\!]\!:\!\!\!& x\!\!\! &\equiv \bbox[4px,border:1px solid #c00]{19}\\
\end{array}$

---

**Or** $\bmod 100\!:\,\ { \dfrac{-1}{-79}\equiv\dfrac{99}{21}\equiv \dfrac{33}7\,\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{R}_{\phantom{|}}}\equiv\, \dfrac{133}7}\equiv \bbox[4px,border:1px solid #c00]{19}\,\ $ by $\,\small\rm\color{#c00}R = $ [inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242).

---

**Or** by CRT: $\bmod \color{#0a0}{25}\!:\ x\equiv {\large \frac{1}{79}\equiv \frac{1}4\equiv \,\frac{\!\!-24}4}\equiv \color{#0a0}{-6}.\ $ $\!\bmod\color{#c00} 4\!:\ x\equiv {\large \frac{1}{79}\equiv \frac{1}{-1}}\equiv -1,\ $ so $-1^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\equiv x \equiv \color{#0a0}{6\!+\!25}j\equiv 2\!+\!j\iff \color{#c00}{j\equiv 1}$ $\iff x = -6\!+\!25(\color{#c00}{1\!+\!4n}) = \bbox[4px,border:1px solid #c00]{19}^{\phantom{|}}\!+\!100n$

**Beware** $ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is valid only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. In particular it is valid to cancel $\,3\,$ in $\,99/21\,$ above. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score 5):

You have $79x\equiv 1 \bmod 100$ which is the same as $79x+100y=1$ for integers $x$ and $y$.

Values of $x$ and $y$ can be determined by using the Euclidean algorithm for highest common factor (=1) on the pair $100, 79$

$100=79+21$

$79=63+16$

$21=16+5$

$16=15+1$

Then reverse:

$1=16-3\times 5=16-3\times (21-16)=4\times 16-3\times 21=4\times (79-3\cdot 21)-3\times 21=4\times 79-15\times 21=4\times 79-15\times (100-79)=19\times 79-15\times 100$

whence $x=19$

Comment: @OP Beware that this common *back-substitution* method is notoriously error prone. It is usually much easier to propagate the linear combinations in the *forward* direction as in Bernards's answer, or my answer (either the fractional form, or the non-fractional form linked in the first sentence).

Comment: @BillDubuque Fair comment - it is as well to have practical methods of computing these things, and I agree that the back-propagation method is error-prone in practice. If you want a very brief solution here, noting that $79=80-1$ and $80+20=100$ gives $(80-1)(20-1)\equiv 1 \bmod 100$ with a lot less work - but that depends on special features of the problem.

Comment: That's equivalent to what I wrote since $\,20\equiv -80\,$ so $\,20\!-\!1\equiv -(80\!+\!1).\,$ The reason I present it that way is because it is a special case of a [general method to invert a  unit + nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242), said with analytic intuition $\,1/(1\!-\!80) \equiv 1\!+\!80\!+\!\color{#c00}{80^2\!+\cdots}\equiv 1\!+\!80\ $ by $\ 0\equiv \color{#c00}{80^2+\cdots}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Once again an acute comment. I hadn't seen your answer when I responded to your comment: the general unit+nilpotent inversion is better sense for learning. I was conscious that he way I put it was opportunistic.

Comment: @BillDubuque out of curiousity, why is back-substitution error-prone? What did you mean by that? Many thanks!

Comment: @Mike Many students make mistakes performing back-substituion (or have difficulties remembering or applying it). I've lost count of the number of times I've seen such. Otoh, far fewer errors seem to occur during forward propagation - which seems to be of lower mental complexity (essentially row operations as I explain [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242).)

Comment: @Mark Yes, I've now clarified that in my answer (showing the geometric series). Thanks for constructive feedback (always welcome).

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks @BillDubuque !

Answer (score 2):

Simply multiply both sides by the inverse of $79\bmod 100$. To determine it, it's easy: use the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to find the coefficients of a *Bézout's relation* between $79$ and $100$.

\begin{array}{rrrrc}
r_i&u_i&v_i&q_i \\\hline
100 & 0 & 1 \\
79 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
21 & -1 & 1 & 3 \\
16 & 4 &-3 & 1 \\
5 & -5 & 4 & 3 \\
1 & \color{red}{19} & -15 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Note that this boils down to the same equations as in the fractional form in my answer (= first $2$ columns above), except there we optimized by using (signed)  *least magnitude* remainders, which eliminates  $\,79x\equiv 1\,$ and $\,16 x\equiv 4\,$ above. This optimization often reduces the work by a factor of $2.\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

$79\equiv 4\pmod {25}\\79 \equiv 3\pmod 4\\
79^{79} \equiv 4^{79} \equiv 4^{-1}\pmod {25}\equiv 19\pmod {25}\\
79^{79} \equiv 79\equiv 3 \pmod 4$

What is the smallest number that is equivalent to $19 \pmod {25}$ and $3 \pmod 4$?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a way to do inverse without the messy extended GCD calculations.
Just do regular GCD calculations, and write down the intermediates.

Example, **GCD(100,79)**: 100 79 21 16 5 1 → gcd(100,79)=1

1
5  → -floor(1/5*16) = -3 = inverse of 5 (mod 16)
16 → -floor(-3/16*21) = 4 = inverse of 16 (mod 21)
21 → -floor(4/21*79) = -15 = inverse of 21 (mod 79)
79 → -floor(-15/79*100) = **19 = inverse of 79 (mod 100)**
100

If only the last inverse is needed, you can skip some calculations.
Ignoring signs, every fractions below are convergents of $\frac{19}{100}$:

$$\frac{1}{5}, \frac{3}{16}, \frac{4}{21}, \frac{15}{79}, \frac{19}{100}$$

Since the gap $|\frac{3}{16} - \frac{4}{21}| = \frac{1}{16\times21} < \frac{1}{100}$, we can skip 2 entries in the table:

$$79^{-1} \text{ (mod 100)} ≡ (-1)^3 \lfloor \frac{-3}{16}*100 \rfloor ≡ 19$$

see https://www.hpmuseum.org/forum/thread-446-post-113586.html#pid113586

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binomial expansion:
$$79^{79}\equiv (80-1)^{79}\equiv A\cdot 100+{79\choose 1}\cdot 80-1\equiv 6320-1\equiv 6319\equiv 19\pmod{100}.$$