# Find the smallest $x$ for $9x \equiv 3 \pmod {23}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$9x \equiv 3 \pmod {23}$

How to derive the smallest $x$. I understand I can use the extended euclidean algorithm for eg $19x = 1 \pmod {35}$.

However, I not too sure how to work on it when it is $3 \pmod {23}$.

I am able to reach the step of $1 = -5(9) + 2(23$) after going thru the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: As $3$ is relatively prime to $23$, $9x\equiv 3\iff 3x\equiv 1$. Guessing shows that $23+1=24=3\cdot 8$ is a multiple of $3$. Indeed, $9\cdot 8=72=3\cdot 23+3$.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, great, but this already means that $-5$ is the multiplicative inverse of $9$ modulo $23$, as $(-5)\cdot 9\equiv 1 \pmod{23}$. So you have
$$x\equiv (-5)\cdot 9x\equiv (-5)\cdot 3=-15\equiv 8 \pmod{23}$$
Among these, $8$ is the smallest positive number.

Answer (score 0):

As you computed, $9(-5)\equiv 1\pmod {23}\implies 9(-5)3\equiv 3\pmod {23}\implies 9(-15)\equiv 3\pmod{23}$ $\implies 9(8)\equiv3\pmod{23}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\ 23\!:\,\ 9x\equiv 3\iff x\equiv \dfrac{3}{9}\equiv \dfrac{1}3\equiv \dfrac{8}{24}\equiv \dfrac{8}1$

**Remark** $\ $ We used [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130934/23500) for computing inverses $\rm\:mod\ p\:$ prime.

**Beware** $\ $ One can employ fractions $\rm\ x\equiv b/a\ $ in modular arithmetic (as above) only when the fractions have denominator $ $ *coprime* $ $ to the modulus $ $ (else the fraction may not *uniquely exist,* $ $  i.e. the equation $\rm\: ax\equiv b\,\ (mod\ m)\:$ might have no solutions, or more than one solution). The reason why such fraction arithmetic works here (and in analogous contexts) will become clearer when one learns about the *universal* properties of fraction rings (*localizations*).

Answer (score 0):

$ _{_{_{x}}}$

(This is certainly a smaller $x$ than any other solution has)

(From reading "Littlewood's Miscellany" - highly recommended)

Answer (score 0):

We employ an algorithm that was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3897515/432081).

$\alpha-$Solve:
$\;9x \equiv 3 \pmod{23}, \text{ and } \; 23 = 9 \cdot 2 + 5,\quad -3 + 1 \cdot 9 = 6$

$\alpha-$Solve:
$\;5x \equiv 6 \pmod{9}, \text{ and } \; 9 = 5 \cdot 1 + 4,\quad -6 + 2\cdot 5 = 4$

$\alpha-$Solve:
$\;4x \equiv 4 \pmod{5},  \text{ ANS: } \; x = 1 \text{ is the least residue solution}.$

Propagating backward,

Solve $5x = 6 + 1 \cdot 9, \text{ ANS: } \; x = 3$

Solve $9x = 3 + 3 \cdot 23, \text{ ANS: } \; x = 8$

$\text{ANSWER: }  x = 8 \text{ is the least natural number satisfying }$
$\quad 9x \equiv 3 \pmod{23}$