# Modular arithmetic to find the mod of a large number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

If $x \equiv 23 \bmod 317$ and $x \equiv 25 \bmod 331$, what is $x \bmod 104927$? What techniques are typically used to solve problems of this nature? It doesn't seem clear to me that it can be solved straightforwardly.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem should ring the bell.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time applying it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x = 25+331n,\, $ so $\,{\rm mod}\ 317\!:\ 23\equiv x = 25+331n\,\Rightarrow\, 14n\equiv -2\,\Rightarrow\, 7n\equiv -1\,$ so, by [Gauss's algorithm,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130934/242) $\, n\equiv -1/7\equiv -45/315 \equiv 272/(-2)\equiv -136.\,$ So $\,x\equiv 25-331(136)\pmod{317\cdot 331}$