# Prove prime $p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b\,$ without using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

Let: $p$ $\in \mathbb{P}$ $\wedge$ $n_{1},n_{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then: $p|(n_{1}n_{2})\implies p|n_{1} \vee \space p|n_{2} $

This little hypothesis is straightforward while using fundamental theorem of arithmetic. I also know that this can be proved directly by the use of the contraposition for the above implication. However, I wonder how to do this without referring to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic or to contraposition. I think that this must be very easy, but I can't see it right now. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/885221/242) for a few proofs, including a direct proof by descent using the Division algorithm. This also includes further elaboration on the proofs using the GCD Distributive Law in Xam's answer, its Bezout form in Leox's answer.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let suppose that $p\not\mid n_1$, so $\gcd(p,n_1)=1$. Now, since $p\mid n_1n_2$ and $p\mid pn_2$, then by the [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85565/133781) of $\gcd$ we have $$p\mid \gcd(pn_2, n_1n_2)=n_2\gcd(p,n_1)^{*}=n_2.$$

In (*) we've used the property $\gcd(ac,bc)=c\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: So easy?????????????????????????????????

Comment: Btw, thanks for help.

Comment: @MIT it's easy if you have practice.  I suggest you that in order to get familiarity with these simple proofs try to prove that property (*) that I've used. Good luck.

Comment: I would start the same way, then use Gauss theorem : since $p\mid n_1n_2$ and $\gcd(p,n_1)=1$, we see that $p\mid n_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $p\not\mid n_1$. Then there exist integers $x,y$ such that $px+n_1 y=1.$ Multiple both sides by $n_2$
$$
p (x  n_2)+ n_1 n_2 y =n_2.
$$
$p$ divides LHS   thus $p \mid n_2.$

Comment: This is the Bezout form of the proof in Xam's answer. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) where I prrecisely highlight the analogy. See also the answer linked in my comment on the question.

Comment: Are you suggesting to me that I should delete my answer?

Comment: No, why would you think that? Rather, I gave a link so that readers can learn how these common proofs are related.