# Find any two integers that satisfy $19x+47y = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find two integers that satisfy $19x+47y = 1$? Is there some technique to finding 2 numbers? I can't find any 2 numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ that make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: Try the extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: @PeterPhipps no mod here so we cant do that, I dont think there is any 2 whole integer solutions to this problem

Comment: What do you mean by "whole number"?  Some (most?)  people exclude negative integers from that.

Comment: Just to say:  if you meant "non-negative integer" then it is is obvious that this can not be done (the least non-zero number you can write that way is $19$).

Comment: you can use any integer including negative

Comment: @lulu I tried many many numbers but didnt find any 2 integers that worked, so I dont think there are any

Comment: Then please edit your post to sat "integers" instead of "whole numbers".  As to your problem, of course the euclidean algorithm works.  Just try it.  Indeed, one solution is very small...you can discover it by trial and error.

Comment: @lulu can you please show how to find two integers with a worked example, I dont understand the answer below, there is no mod so how do we use EE

Comment: Euclid's algorithm was invented thousands of years before modular arithmetic.  Just follow the steps sketched in that posted solution.  Or just write out the small multiples of $19$ and $47$.   Really, trial and error takes only a few seconds.

Comment: @lulu Using EE i get the result of 1 ?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100814/how-to-find-the-numbers-of-bezout-identity-for-two-numbers) is a fully worked example, just change the numbers.  Really, though, for such small numbers trial and error is more efficient.

Comment: @lulu I followed that step by step and didnt get integer solutions that worked ?

Comment: Then please try trial and error.  By the way, the posted solution actually includes the full answer.

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU

Comment: I made a mistake in EE algorithm, now I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A popular technique is to use the division algorithm.

Notice that

$$47=2 \cdot 19 + 9$$

$$19=2 \cdot 9 +1$$

Now $1$ can be expressed in terms of $19$

$$1=19- 2\cdot 9$$

Also,
$$9=47-2\cdot 19$$

Combining both yields,

$$19-2\cdot (47-2\cdot 19)=1$$
$$5\cdot 19-2\cdot 47=1$$

Now notice that,
$$lcm(19,47)=19\cdot 47$$
and $19\cdot 47 -  47\cdot 19 =0$

Add $0$ to the above solution yields a general solution

$$(5+47t)\cdot 19-(2+19t)\cdot 47 =0$$

Also for any numbers, $a,b$

We can find solutions for

$$ax+by=k \gcd{(a,b)}$$

Then express $a$ in terms of $b$
$$a=b\cdot q_1+r_1 $$, where $r_1$ is the remainder of $a$ upon division by $b$ and $0\leq r_1\lt b$

Then, similarly express $b$ in terms of $r_1$
$$b=r_1\cdot q_2 + r_2$$.

Continue this until $r_k=\gcd(a,b)$

Comment: Even with this I cant see any whole numbers where the above is true, I now do not belive there exists any 2 numbers that the qn is true for but thanks for trying !

Comment: Why $x=5, y=-2$ do not satisfy you?

Comment: $x=5,y=-2$ satisfy the equation,

Answer (score 1):

Consider the continued fraction of $\frac{47}{19}$:

$$ \frac{47}{19}=2+\frac{1}{\frac{19}{9}}=2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{9}}=[2;2,9] $$
truncate it and expand it back:
$$ [2;2] = 2+\frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{2}. $$
We have that $\frac{5}{2}$ and $\frac{47}{19}$ are consecutive convergents of the same continued fraction, hence their difference is $\pm\frac{1}{2\cdot 19}$.
Indeed 
$$ \frac{47}{19}-\frac{5}{2}=\frac{94-95}{38}=\frac{-1}{38} $$
leads to
$$ 47\cdot 2 - 5\cdot 19 = -1 $$
$$ 47\cdot(-2) + 19\cdot 5 = 1 $$
$$ 47(19-2)+19(5-47) = 1 $$
$$ \color{red}{47\cdot 17 - 19\cdot 42 = 1.}$$

Comment: I think the $\pm$ bit depends only on the number of terms in the CF before/after truncation.

Comment: @JMP: exactly.$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(19,47)=1$ then the [Bezout Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) assures that your equation can be solved in $\mathbb Z$.

Of course if $(a,b)$ is a solution, then all the couples $(a+k47,\, b-k19)$ are solutions as well.

$(a,b)$ are given by the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).