# Euclidean algorithm variant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Normal Euclidean algorithm iterates $(a$ mod $b, b)$ for $a>b$. I have noticed that iterating $(a$ mod $ b, a)$ (keeping the $a$ fixed through descent) will also give the GCD. Can anyone show why is that so? I have no experience in proving.

Comment: This is [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3230/242) and generally it works only for *prime* $a.\ $ Did you forget the many earlier discussions on this in your older posts circa $5$ months ago?

Comment: How does this work when $a = 9$ and $b = 6$?

Comment: I went back to this after my post from 2 days ago. Actually I was trying to understand why when $p|ab$ the $p|(p$ mod $ a)b$

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ p\mid pb,ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid (\color{#c00}{p\!-\!ka})b.\ $ But $\,\color{#c00}{p\!-\!ka}\,=\, p\bmod a\, $ for some $k\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque is it possible I can contact you via email or some other portal where you are active which allows private messages?

Comment: I wish to ask you about your history in math, which college you went to, how much did you self study etc. I like how you always have a different view on stuff.

Comment: @Michael Remove the at-sign and append google.com to my username to get my mail address

Comment: @Bill can you please confirm if you received my email?

Comment: @EricTowers well it would work for $a = 9$ and $b = 6$, but it would not for example for $a = 14$ and $b = 5$. As Bill said it will always work for prime $a$.